# Jquery focus/submit acting weird in Chrome-Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, cross-browser, jquery-events

Actually ( on the website ) I have a form which is in a Box.
So not to exhaust the limited place in that box, the contact-form pops up to its full size, only when the inputs (textarea, select, too) gets focused.

When the submit Button gets hit, a AJAX request gets fired up.
Under Firefox works everything great. But in Chrome:

When I click the submit button, the form gets back to its usual size and no AJAX-Request gets fired.

Please feel free to check it out by yourself:
http://jsfiddle.net/uUgaZ/

The actual Code-Parts which are involved:

```js
    $('#helpkontakt').submit(function(){
    alert('ON MY WAY!');
});
 $("#helpkontakt textarea, input, select").focus(function() {
    $("#helpkontakt").css("height", "auto");
});
$("#helpkontakt textarea, input, select, #submit").focusout(function() {
    $("#helpkontakt").css("height", "200px");
});
```

```html
<form action="" accept-charset="utf-8" role="application" class="ym-form ym-columnar clearfix" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" id="helpkontakt" style="height: 200px;">
    <div class="ym-fbox-text">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Ihr Name" class="full" value="Max Mustermann" id="name"name="name">    
    </div>
    <div class="ym-fbox-text">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Ihre Email" class="full" value="test@test.de" id="email" name="email">
    </div>
    <div class="ym-fbox-text">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Telefonnr. für Rückruf" class="full" value="" id="tel" name="tel">
    </div>
    <div class="ym-fbox-select">
        <select class="full" id="topic" name="topic">    
            <option label="Ideenvorschlag" value="Ideenvorschlag">Ideenvorschlag</option>    
            <option label="Verbesserungsvorschlag" value="Verbesserungsvorschlag">Verbesserungsvorschlag</option>    
            <option label="Fehlermeldung" value="Fehlermeldung">Fehlermeldung</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="ym-fbox-msg">
        <textarea cols="80" rows="24" placeholder="[Die erste Zeile ist für den Betreff]                                                                    Ab hier ihre Nachricht" class="full" id="nachricht" name="nachricht"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;">
        <input type="hidden" id="hiddenTyp" value="Ausschluss Kriterien für Artikel" name="hiddenTyp">             
   </div>
   <div style="margin: 0; padding: 0 1.5em 0 0;" class="ym-fbox-button">
       <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Absenden" id="submit" name="submit">
   </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your focusout function is running before you are able to fully click on the submit button, you could solve it like this. http://jsfiddle.net/uUgaZ/2/

Basically, I added this:

```
var submitClicked = false;
$('#submit').on("mousedown", function() {
    submitClicked = true;
}).on("mouseup", function() {
    submitClicked = false;
});
```

and modified the `focusout` to be like this:

```
$("#helpkontakt textarea, input, select, #submit").focusout(function() {
    if(!submitClicked) {
        $("#helpkontakt").css("height", "200px");
    }
});
```

so if the `focusout` happens because the mouse is down on the submit button, it wont execute. This wont cause a pause in the `focusout` execution and it wont require the user to click a certain speed (to happen within that pause).

Comment: I think if we are really realistic this solution is a bit cleaner than user1s. So i will check this as the final accepted answer.
Thanks smerny, i guess i love you, too ;)

Comment: another way to solve: convert the focusout() into a function and create a cancel button that calls the function.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that is because, when you try to click the button, it focuses out and the focusout event is fired and button is hidden.

to resolve this you can do this.

```
$("#helpkontakt textarea, input, select, #submit").focusout(function() {
setTimeout(function(){
$("#helpkontakt").css("height", "200px");
} ,100);
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uUgaZ/1/)**

Comment: Ohh, Dude i guess i love you ;)

Comment: @MichaelHirn glad i could help. `100` in the code is in millisecond. You can increase or decrease that as you please.

Answer (score 0):

Simply wrapping your focusout function contents into a setTimeout did the trick.

This should handle it fine. I got the alert when submitting. Hope this helps.

http://jsfiddle.net/uUgaZ/3/

```
$("#helpkontakt textarea, input, select").focusout(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#helpkontakt").css("height", "200px");
    },500);
});
```